# Zeppelin Null Pointer Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I wrote this simple code in my zeppelin notebook

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlConext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs:///user/admin/foo/2018.csv")
df.printSchema()
```

Earlier it was not able to find spark-csv. so I added it as a dependency to spark1 and spark2 interpreters. But when I run this code I get an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:614)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:493)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
```

This file has just 300 rows. So I don't think it causes any memory issues. I have a 4 node cluster, so how can I determine where is the log file where a more detailed error may reside?

Comment: You can get more clear error message if you use zeppelin 0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I resolved it. It seems Zeppelin uses Scala 2.10 I had added dependency of Scala csv for version 2.11 that caused the null pointer error.

I went and changed my dependency to 2.10 and restarted the interpreter and now it works fine.